# setResult and OnAcivityResult issue in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities: **A, B and C**

the main Activity is **A**:

```
public class A extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i("TESTING", "OnAcivity Invoked");
    }

    public void start_B_forResult() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_UPDATE);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Activity **B** is mediator between **A** and **C**:

```
public class B extends Activity{

    public void call_C () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_UPDATE);
        finish();
    }
    // ... other functions

}
```

and this is the Activity **C**:

```
public class C extends Activity{

    public void finishC() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
    // ... other funcitons
}
```

so when I go back from **C** to **A**, onAcitivitResult is not invoked even when I set the result

```
setResult(REQUEST_OK);
```

I tried to go back from **B** to **A**, `onActivityResult` is invoked normally

so how to move this result from B throw C to A, so `onActivityResult` in A can be invoked ?

what i want is to let onActivityResult be invoked when i go back from C to A

Comment: Why are you finishing activity B after startActivityForResult for C? It's likely C is reporting back to nothing.

Comment: Too, B hasn't onActivityresult Method, B wil be closed ont that method, before setting result (setResult)

Comment: Because B has nothing to do except properties of how to lunch C @Losin'Me

Comment: What else does Activity B do? Will it be seen or used by the user? If not, then why not just give A the properties to A? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is self explained, A can't get the result from C directly, you have to get the result from C to B, and next, resend that result from B to A, B should be the bridge, the result needs to go across him from go and back

the main Activity is **A**:

```
public class A extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if ( requestCode == Util.REQUEST_UPDATE ){
             Log.i("TESTING A result", resultCode);//log the Result, it depends from the result given by C

      }
    }

    public void start_B_forResult() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_UPDATE);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Activity **B** is mediator between **A** and **C**:

```
public class B extends Activity{

    public void call_C () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_UPDATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if ( requestCode == Util.REQUEST_UPDATE ){
             Log.i("TESTING B result", resultCode);
             Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
             setResult(resultCode,returnIntent);//set result from C to A, CANCELLED or OK
             finish();//And then, finish the activity, here is the correctly finished, not in call_C upper function, if you finish in call_C, the result never will come back from C to B


      }
    }
    // ... other functions

}
```

and this is the Activity **C**:

```
public class C extends Activity{

    public void finishC() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        //setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
    // ... other funcitons
}
```

Comment: This is good. This would work providing that @MBH removes the finish(); call in their `callC()` function in Activity B like me and Brian suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent **Activity** for childs **A**,**B**,**C**. And catch result in parent activity.

> For example :

**Parent Activity :**

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case ActivityRequests.FIRST_ACTIVITY_REQUEST :
                //do stuff
                break;
            case ActivityRequests.SECOND_ACTIIVITY_REQUEST :
                //do stuff
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void startB() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,B.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequests.FIRST_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);
    }

    public void startC() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,C.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequests.SECOND_ACTIIVITY_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**Children's :**

```
public class A extends ParentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startB();
    }
}

public class B extends ParentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startC();
    }
}

public class C extends ParentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

*Be complexive :)*

Comment: being complexive is good for now. But when u wanna check your own code after a while, it will be complex to get it so well

Answer (score 0):

The activity that requests for the result is the activity that will receive the result. In your case, Activity C was started by Activity B so C will report back to B when it has a result, not A. Since you `finish()` B right after you start C, the result from C is essentially lost.

Perhaps what you could do is get rid of `finish()` right after starting C, implement on `onActivityResult` in B to receive the result from C, and then pass the result back to A from B.